# How can i automartically make wiki from the release notes that i am generating through extension called Generate release notes in release pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am trying to generate the release notes in the azure devops release pipeline. My aim is I want to get the release notes based on the changes that is made in the current build. I am using one extension called Generate release notes. It is generating the release notes which i required but it is storing that note in the path which is not specified by me. How can I get access to that path and how can i automatically make wiki from it?

i have tried using extension Generate Release Notes in the azure devops release pipeline and after that I also add one extension to automatically make the wiki called Wiki updater task. The logs for the Generate release notes are as follows:-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmN0S.png)
the logs for the wiki updater task are as follows:-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LP8oE.png)